# Parse JSON string to Database

Tags: php, mysql, objective-c, xcode, json

I'm having trouble parsing a JSON string to my MYSQL database.
This is the JSON-string sent to the server:

```
    [{"Description":"Detta √§r mitt quiz!","Title":"Mitt Quiz","Category":"Music","Language":"Swedish","Difficulty":1},{"QuestionNr1":{"WrongAnswer3":"Visby","WrongAnswer1":"Stockholm","RightAnswer":"Uppsala","WrongAnswer2":"Ume√•","Question":"Vilken stad bor jag i?"},"QuestionNr2":{"WrongAnswer3":"Visby","WrongAnswer1":"Stockholm","RightAnswer":"Uppsala","WrongAnswer2":"Ume√•","Question":"Vilken stad bor jag inte i?"}}]
```

This is the data before calling [mArray JSonrepresentation]; on it

```
(
    {
    Category = Music;
    Description = "Detta \U00e4r mitt quiz!";
    Difficulty = 1;
    Language = Swedish;
    Title = "Mitt Quiz";
},
    {
    QuestionNr1 =         {
        Question = "Vilken stad bor jag i?";
        RightAnswer = Uppsala;
        WrongAnswer1 = Stockholm;
        WrongAnswer2 = "Ume\U00e5";
        WrongAnswer3 = Visby;
    };
    QuestionNr2 =         {
        Question = "Vilken stad bor jag inte i?";
        RightAnswer = Uppsala;
        WrongAnswer1 = Stockholm;
        WrongAnswer2 = "Ume\U00e5";
        WrongAnswer3 = Visby;
    };
}
```

)

I'm using a POST method of the ASIHTTPRequest but don't know how to receive this on the server side and parse it with PHP to my database.

Can someone point me in the right direction and I would be very happy!

//Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

```
$json = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}';
var_dump(json_decode($json));
```

loop over $json and build sql query

Comment: and what about `but don't know how to receive this on the server side `?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're `POST`ing the JSON-string in a named variable, the contents will be available in the request payload, readable from `stdin`.

```
// Read contents from stdin
$json_string = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

If you're sending the JSON-string as a named POST-variable, it's contents are in `$_POST['varname']`.

To parse a JSON-string in PHP, you will use the [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function. Parsing success can be checked using the [`json_last_error`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php) function.

```
// Parse a JSON-string into PHP native equivalents
$json_parsed = json_decode($json_string);

if (json_last_error() === JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
    var_dump($json_parsed);
} else {
    // Error parsing JSON
}
```